# Using single quotes with std::cout for printing a string actually prints numbers

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << 'hello';
  return 0;
}
```

This program output is:

```
1701604463
```

I wonder why it actually runs, although the compiler gives a warning message: `character constant too long for its type`.

What these numbers actually mean, are they garbage digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [multicharacter literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) which has type `int`.

> Multicharacter literal, e.g. 'AB', has type int and
>   implementation-defined value.